# What is an O(n)-approximation?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, algorithm-analysis, approximation

I see the following notations used:

- $O(1)$-approximation
- $O(n)$-approximation
- $\Omega(n)$-approximation

Can someone please explain what they mean?

I know what an approximation is with a normal constant approximation (2-approx, 2/3-approx, etc).
And I know what $O(n)$, $\Omega(n)$ mean, but I just don't understand what they mean exactly in this context.

**The way I understand it:**  With $O(n)$, $\Omega(n)$ the approximation gets worse when the size of the input increases, $\Omega(n)$ is a lower bound (the approx is at least an $n$-approx) and $O(n)$ is a maximum bound, the approximation does not get worse than $n$-approx (so if n=100, and we have an algorithm that is a $\Omega(n)$-approximation then we have a 100-approx? the approximation algorithm will give an answer that is 100 times worse than OPT or worse?).

With $O(1)$ it is constant (a constant factor but we just don't care what the constant is, it's just bounded by some fixed $C$).
But I am not sure my interpretation is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minimization problem has the following generic form.

For each instance $\mathcal{I}$ there is a set $F_{\mathcal{I}}$ of feasible solutions and an objective function $\phi_{\mathcal{I}}\colon F_{\mathcal{I}} \to \mathbb{R}_+$. The goal is to find a feasible solution which minimizes the value of the objective function.

Often instances also comes with a natural size function (sometimes several). We denote the size of an instance $\mathcal{I}$ by $|\mathcal{I}|$.

A (deterministic) approximation algorithm for a minimization problem gets as input an instance $\mathcal{I}$ and outputs a feasible solution $A(\mathcal{I}) \in F_{\mathcal{I}}$ (sometimes we allow an approximation algorithm to relax the feasibility constraints — such an algorithm is known as a *bicriteria* approximation algorithm). The algorithm has approximation ratio $\rho(n)$, or that it is a $\rho(n)$-approximation (just different terminology), if for all $\mathcal{I}$,
$$
\phi_{\mathcal{I}}(A(\mathcal{I})) \leq \rho(|\mathcal{I}|) \min_{x \in F_{\mathcal{I}}} \phi_{\mathcal{I}}(x).
$$
In words, the approximation algorithm is guaranteed to returns a solution which is within a multiplicative factor of $\rho(n)$ of the optimal solution, where $n$ is the size of the instance. (Sometimes this definition is relaxed by also allowing a small additional additive error.)

For a randomized approximation algorithm, we require this guarantee to hold in expectation, with constant probability, or with high probability — different algorithms will have different guarantees.

Maximization problems are handled similarly, the guarantee becoming
$$
\phi_{\mathcal{I}}(A(\mathcal{I})) \geq \rho(|\mathcal{I}|)^{-1} \max_{x \in F_{\mathcal{I}}} \phi_{\mathcal{I}}(x).
$$

A specific feasible solution $y \in F_{\mathcal{I}}$ is a $\rho$-approximation if $$\phi_{\mathcal{I}}(y) \leq \rho \min_{x \in F_{\mathcal{I}}} \phi_{\mathcal{I}}(x). $$

---

When we say that an algorithm has an approximation ratio of $O(n)$, we mean that it has an approximation ratio of $\rho(n)$ for some function $\rho(n) = O(n)$. Alternatively, for every instance of size $n$ it gives a solution which is within an $O(n)$ factor of the optimum.

As usual with big O notation, if an algorithm is an $O(n)$-approximation, this doesn't preclude it being an $O(1)$-approximation: the promised approximation ratio is just an *upper bound* on the actual performance of the algorithm.

When we say that an algorithm has an approximation ratio of $\Omega(n)$, we mean that any function $\rho(n)$ for which it the algorithm has an approximation ratio of $\rho(n)$ satisfies $\rho(n) = \Omega(n)$. This means that there is a sequence of instances $y_n$ whose size tends to infinity on which the solutions produced by the algorithm have an objective value which is an $\Omega(n)$ factor more than the optimum.

Comment: Thanks, I just need an extra clarification if you don't mind, if OPT is (upper) bounded by n, and we have some approximation Algorithm ALG a 3-approximation, so we say in this situation that since 3ALG $\geq$ OPT and since OPT is generally n or less, so in this example can I say that that ALG is considered Ω(n)-approx (Ω(n) more than the optimum - lower bound is n)? and since the it's 3-approx, so it's also an O(1)-approx where the constant is 3 and we're (upper) bounded by 3 times worse than the optimum?

Comment: It’s not the case that $3=\Omega(n)$, so no.